# Drag image behind a transparent png

Tags: drag-and-drop, draggable, transparent, drag, snap.svg

I am adding 2 images - the top one is a transparent png.  I want to be able to drag the bottom image without moving the top one, but can't seem to figure out how to be able to drag it.

Using jQuery I was able to do this using this method by passing the event from one element to another.

```
$("#image-up").draggable();
$("#image-fg").on("mousedown", function(event) {
    $("#image-up").trigger(event);
});
```

Is there a way to do this with snap svg?

Comment: You can possibly just put css pointer-events: none on the one you don't want to steal from the drag, and just a normal el.drag() in snap.

Comment: The css pointer-events: none did not work.  The snap drag class will work, it even gives me the ability to rotate the image so that is an added bonues.

Answer (score 1):

I found this snap svg plugin.  It is not exactly what I was after but close enough to start with and after making a couple of changes to this plugin and I now have what I want.

http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-freetransform